# In elm, how can I pipe a value to a function as an argument other than the last one?

Tags: elm

I'm new to elm and to be honest struggling a bit to get my head around certain concepts right now. I'm not sure how clear my question is but this is what I'm trying to do.

for example:

```
aFunction value1 value2
```

is equivalent to:

```
value2
  |> aFunction value1
```

but what if I want to pass `value1` to `aFunction` through a pipe instead of `value2`?

at the moment I'm using something like this:

```
value1
  |> (\x y -> aFunction y x) value2
```

However, it strikes me as a bit of a kludge, to be honest. Is there a more elegant way to do this?

What I'm trying to code in practice is part of quite a long chain of pipes which would be impractical (or at least unreadable) to do using an expression with lots of parentheses.

Comment: Well designed libraries choose the ordering of arguments wisely so that the one on which it would be more logical to pipe comes last. Don't hesitate to ask yourself this question when defining a new function and encourage library authors to do the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [flip](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/5.1.1/Basics#flip) function (which is just the function you are defining in-line with the lambda expression):

```
value1 |> (flip aFunction) value2
```

Comment: Thanks, chepner! I hadn't discovered the flip function yet. I'm still wondering if there's a good way to do it for functions with more than 2 parameters, though?

Comment: @MTaylor defining `aFunctionWithMoreConvenientArguments x y z = aFunction z x y` is probably your best option.

Comment: @MTaylor You can probably start playing around with atrocious-looking compositions involving `flip`. `flip . flip` itself, interestingly but unhelpfully, appears to be a 2-argument version of `id`. `(flip .) . flip :: (a -> b -> c -> d) -> b -> c -> a -> d`, though, rotates the argument of a 3-argument function. I don't have any advice on how to design a desired permutation of arguments, though.

Answer (score 0):

As per @chepner's answer, `flip` seems to be the best way to do this for functions with 2 arguments.

Given that there doesn't seem to be any built in solution to the wider question of how to do this for functions having more than 2 arguments, I came up with the following.

*I'm really not sure if this is likely to be particularly useful in real life*, but it was (at least) an interesting exercise for me as I'm really still learning fairly basic stuff:

```
module RotArgs exposing (..)

rot3ArgsL1 func = \y z x -> func x y z

rot3ArgsL2 func = \z x y -> func x y z

rot4ArgsL1 func = \x y z w -> func w x y z

rot4ArgsL2 func = \y z w x -> func w x y z

rot4ArgsL3 func = \z w x y -> func w x y z
```

So, for example `rot3ArgsL1` takes a 3-argument function and returns a version of that function in which the *expected* order of arguments has been rotated 1 place to the left... and so forth.

It would enable things like:

```
import RotArgs exposing (..)

someFunction one two three =
  ...whatever

...

one
  |> (rot3ArgsL1 someFunction) two three
```

Obviously `RotArgs` could easily be extemded to functions of more than 4 arguments, though that seems likely to be increasingly less useful the more arguments are added.